# wpf listbox databinding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox

i need to fill a listbox with items one by one
like the list to be filled with one item than after 1/5 sec an other item will be added to the list

any ideas how this could be done (in wpf)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you bind the ListBox to an `ObservableCollection<T>`, you can only modify the collection from the UI thread. So you could use a `DispatcherTimer`, which raises the `Tick` event on the UI thread, or use a specialized collection like [this one](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/04/17/wpf-binding-to-an-asynchronous-collection/) and fill it from another thread

Answer (score 0):

In the Loaded event of the window or control, execute the method to load the first item of data
by calling the BeginInvoke method of the System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject for the
UI element, and specify a System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority of Background. When
this method has finished generating the data and adding it to the list, add the same method to
the Dispatcher’s queue recursively, each time adding just one item and then queuing the call
to add the next one with a DispatcherPriority of Background.

```
private ObservableCollection<string> numberDescriptions;
// Declare a delegate to wrap the LoadNumber method
private delegate void LoadNumberDelegate(int number);
private void LoadNumber(int number)
{
// Add the number to the observable collection
// bound to the ListBox
numberDescriptions.Add("Number " + number.ToString());
if(number < 10000)
{
// Load the next number, by executing this method
// recursively on the dispatcher queue, with
// a priority of Background.
//
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
DispatcherPriority.Background,
new LoadNumberDelegate(LoadNumber), ++number);
}
}
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
// Initialize an ObservableCollection of strings
numberDescriptions =
new ObservableCollection<string>();
// Set it as the ItemsSource for the ListBox
listBox.ItemsSource = numberDescriptions;
// Execute a delegate to load
// the first number on the UI thread, with
// a priority of Background.
//
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
DispatcherPriority.Background,
new LoadNumberDelegate(LoadNumber), 1);
}
```

see [WPF Recipes in C# 2008](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430210842) Load the Items in a ListBox Asynchronously(pg 460)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to bind a listbox with RSS feed with DataTemplate:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key ="DataRSS" XPath="//item" Source="http://rss.feedsportal.com/c/629/f/502199/index.rss"></XmlDataProvider >
    </UserControl.Resources >

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalAlignment="Center">

            <ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataRSS}}"  Height="516" Margin="0,0,32,0" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="#FF627DAE">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <Grid Width="400" Height="100"   >                                

                            <Image Source="{Binding XPath=enclosure/@url}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  />
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding XPath=title}" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="2"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
</grid>
```